# signup a free trial of google DialogFlow cx service

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I would like to signup for a free trial of google DialogFlow cx service, but their are different links on their website that made me confused?

I created a project on my google account. How can I start a free trial of DialogFlow cx service?
Is their a specific link or is it activated automatically once I add the service to the project?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a customer service question that should be asked at Google customer support. We cannot help with getting you set up for a free trial, your account, or other issues you're having with an off-site vendor or service.

Answer (score 1):

The free trial of Dialogflow CX will start automatically upon using it for the first time and will expire after 12 months. You will receive a $600 credit for the duration of the trial.

You can take a look at the documentation if you want more info here:
https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/pricing